# Rolling up / Cumulative sum of units shipped in the 3 days since first shipment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum, rolling-computation

Its a little hard to explain but ill try my best, please bear with me.

I have a pd with ID, Shipping date and Units.
I want to calculate the units shipped within a 3 day timeframe, and the count should not overlap e.g. my dataframe is as follows.

```
ID          Shipping Date Units Expected output
153131151007    20180801    1   1
153131151007    20180828    1   2
153131151007    20180829    1   0
153131151007    20180904    1   1
153131151007    20181226    2   4
153131151007    20181227    1   0
153131151007    20181228    1   0
153131151007    20190110    1   1
153131151007    20190115    2   3
153131151007    20190116    1   0
153131151011*   20180510    1   2
153131151011*   20180511    1   0
153131151011*   20180513    1   2
153131151011*   20180515    1   0
153131151011*   20180813    1   1
153131151011*   20180822    1   2
153131151011*   20180824    1   0
153131151011*   20190103    1   1
```

The code should check the date, see if there are any shipments in the next 3 days, if there is a shipment, it should sum it in its current date column and make sure it does not consider the summed count for next date calculation.

So for the first ID Shipping date 20181226, it checks 1226,1227,1228 and sum them together and show result in 1226 and it shows 0 in the next 2 cells.

Similarly for 2nd ID 20180510, 0510 is the first date of the shipment in the series. It checks 0510,0511 and 0512 and sums it in 0510 and zeros the rest, which is why 0511 does not consider 0513 and it is a part of other shipment group.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*'],
'Date':[20180801,20180828,20180829,20180904,20181226,20181227,20181228,20190110,20190115,20190116,20180510,20180511,20180513,20180515,20180813,20180822,20180824,20190103],
'Units':[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

Comment: You're missing a curly bracket before the closing parenthesis

Comment: Corrected it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but the results are in wide format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151007','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*','153131151011*'],
'Date':[20180801,20180828,20180829,20180904,20181226,20181227,20181228,20190110,20190115,20190116,20180510,20180511,20180513,20180515,20180813,20180822,20180824,20190103],
'Units':[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

def keep_first(ser):
    ixs = []
    ts = ser.dropna().index[0]
    while ts <= ser.dropna().index.max():
        if ts in ser.dropna().index:
            ixs.append(ts)
            ts+=timedelta(3)
        else:
            ts+=timedelta(1)
    return np.where(ser.index.isin(ixs), ser, 0)

data['Date'] = data['Date'].map(lambda x: parse(str(x))) # parse dates

units = data.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).sum().unstack(0).resample('D').sum() # create resampled units df

units = units.sort_index(ascending=False).rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum().sort_index() # calculate forward-rolling sum

grouped_ix = data.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).sum().unstack(0).index # get indices for actual data

units.loc[grouped_ix].apply(keep_first) # get sums for actual data indices, keep only first
```

Comment: This partially worked and I modified it a little to make it work as per my case. i couldnt figure what was wrong.
I used `stack().reset_index()` to get the df.
I had more than 2000 IDs and for some reason it was not working when I put in all the data. So I ended up sub-setting the data in a loop for each ID and merging them at the end. I got the result I was looking for. Thank you :)